# Locations tracker icon not showing up on map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Currently I'm setting up location services but for some strange reason the tracker icon isn't appearing:
[image: missing tracker icon]

I know it's working because if I add a pin the pin shows up correctly:
[image: map with pin]

I'm not sure why the tracker isn't showing up, here is the code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

  let locationsManager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

  locationsManager.delegate = self
    locationsManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest // sets to best location accuracy
    locationsManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()// requests user location when app is opened
    locationsManager.startUpdatingLocation()// updates user location


  }

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude)
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
    pin.coordinate.latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    pin.coordinate.longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    pin.title = "My current location"
    map.addAnnotation(pin) 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property `showsUsersLocation` to true. https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452682-showsuserlocation

Answer (score 1):

`MKMapView` can display the user location and track user location for you:

```
map.showsUserLocation = true
map.userTrackingMode = .follow
```

There is no need to implement your own location tracking delegate method.

Comment: This is quick and easy but what if I want to add a pin to the location? Before I was doing it in the locationManager function.

Comment: It depends on how you want to add the pin.  If you simply want a pin instead of the blue circle, then you can implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView(_:viewFor:)` and return a pin view for the user location annotation.  If you wanted a series of pins as the user moves then you can use the method you had originally.

Answer (score -2):

Nevermind, figured it out. In viewDidload():

map.showsUserLocation = true